# Regex numbers and letters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm figuring out how get '02' and '05' or any other numbers . I've difficulty when there are letters after numbers ( for example : 'a' and 'b' or any other letters)

```
title = "Nursing informatics S02E05ab Jack"       ->02 and 05
title = "Medical diagnosis   S06E06ku Peter"      ->06 and 06
title = "medical protection  S01E02bc Katharina"  ->01 and 02
```

I tried like this , but it always returns 'None'

```
result = re.search(r"\b(?:e?)?\s*(\d{2,3})(?:[a-z]?)?\b", title, re.IGNORECASE)
```

It should only get number next `S` and `E`. For example, `books 2004` must return `None`.

```
Thank you all
```

Comment: try `re.findall(r'\d+', title)`

Comment: It should only get number next 'S' and 'E'  for example  'books 2004' must return 'None'

Comment: then use `try re.findall(r'[SE](\d+)', title)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\bS(?P<Season>\d+)E(?P<Episode>\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aISIqF/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `S` - a letter `S`
- `(?P<Season>\d+)` - Group "Season": one or more digits
- `E` - a `E` letter
- `(?P<Episode>\d+)` - Group "Episode": one or more digits

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GppXUv):

```py
import re
title = "Nursing informatics S02E05ab Jack" 
m = re.search(r'\bS(?P<Season>\d+)E(?P<Episode>\d+)', title)
if m:
  print( m.groupdict() )
# => {'Season': '02', 'Episode': '05'}
```

Answer (score 4):

A following regex function (findall) can identifies all specified patterns:

```
import re
s = "Nursing informatics S02E05ab Jack"
re.findall('[0-9]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['02', '05']
```